# Ubuntu can't find Wi-Fi driver

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, gnome, 15.10

My newly set-up Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 system isn't able to find a Wi-Fi driver for my laptop. When I boot from a live USB it's able to find the driver easily, and activate it so I can use Wi-Fi. Yet, on the actual system it is unable to do so. Nothing appears in the "Additional Drivers" page.

Is there a way to enable Wi-Fi without the need for an Ethernet cable?

For a bit of extra info, the battery driver seems to be missing as well (battery level always shown as critically low), and I'm on a very old HP Mini laptop. When I use `rfkill list` it shows that everything is unblocked.

The command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` prints:

`01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1508] Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score -1):

Download this file and save it in "Downloads":

http://media.cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/04/32/2480236-Broadcom_Firmware.tar.gz

Installation

```
cd ~/Downloads/
sudo tar xvf 2480236-Broadcom_Firmware.tar.gz -C /lib/firmware/
```

Reboot. From here:
http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/netzwerkkarte-nach-deaktivierung-im-autostart/#post-2480236